# Use cycle for value in template

Tags: django, django-templates

How to access "value" in if condition? Or it's not possible in django tamplates?

Here is my example what I would like to be possible in django, but it doesn't work.

So I have problem with this row "{% if field.data == value %}" How to pass "value" from "for cycle" to if condition?

What is best solution for this?

```
template file
{% for field in form1 %}                                   
    <div class="row pad-col i-l">
        {{ field.errors }}
        <div class="col-sm-5 text-right">
            <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">
                {{ field.label }}
            </label>
        </div>
        {% if field|field_type == 'Select' %}
            <div class="col-sm-7 a-select">
                <div class="a-m">
                    <select class="selectpicker add-i" id="{{ field.id_for_label }}" data-live-search="true" name="{{ field.name }}" tabindex="-98">
                        {% for value, key in field.field.choices %}
                            {% if field.data == value %}
                            <option value="{{ value }}" selected>{{ key }}</option>
                            {% else %}
                            <option value="{{ value }}">{{ key }}</option>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% else %}
            <div class="col-sm-7">
                {{ field }}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}


views.py file
def add_item(request):
    form1 = AddForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form1 = AddForm(data=request.POST)
        if form1.is_valid():
            form1.save()
            return HttpResponse('good')
    return render(request, 'add_item.html', {'form1': form1})
```

Sorry guys. I just solved by myself. It was really stupid idea to customize that way forms when you can just add "***widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'selectpicker add-i', 'data-live-search': 'true'})***" to your form field in forms.py file and all validation is working.

And than instead of this:

```
<select class="selectpicker add-i" id="{{ field.id_for_label }}" data-live-search="true" name="{{ field.name }}" tabindex="-98">
   {% for value, key in field.field.choices %}
      {% if field.data == value %}
        <option value="{{ value }}" selected>{{ key }}</option>
      {% else %}
      <option value="{{ value }}">{{ key }}</option>
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
</select>
```

you just write this:

```
{{ field }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should assign just one controlling var to the iteration, and then call the fields on it (assuming "value" and "key" are part of the field choices), like this:

```
{% for vfield in field.field.choices %}
   {% if field.data == value %}
      <option value="{{ vfield.value }}" selected>{{ vfield.key }}</option>
   {% else %}
      <option value="{{ vfield.value }}">{{ vfield.key }}</option>
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I need to access "value" in second row. In if condition.

Comment: Please update your question with more code about this field choices so we can understand exactly what you need and help you